# I am trying to publish a saleor store on AWS and using Apache

Tags: django, apache, saleor

I have ran published default django project and it was working fine, I was able to access it with domain name then I just replaced the details for saleor and now I am getting 404 not found. Here is my conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/ecom

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/wsgi>
        <Files __init__.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject2 python-home=/home/ubuntu/ecom/ecom python-path=/home/ubuntu/ecom
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject2
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/wsgi/__init__.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Here `/home/ubuntu/ecom` is my project main dir and it contains ecom (virtual env) and saleor folders.
I have added `glintwear.com` my domain in settings.py file of saleor project

**EDIT**
Here is error from error.log file:

```
[Wed Aug 15 01:09:17.240064 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14328:tid 140275526600448] [remote 39.53.22.238:27753] mod_wsgi (pid=14328): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/ecom/$
[Wed Aug 15 01:09:17.240110 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14328:tid 140275526600448] [remote 39.53.22.238:27753] mod_wsgi (pid=14328): Exception occurred processing WSGI scr$
[Wed Aug 15 01:09:17.240269 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14328:tid 140275526600448] [remote 39.53.22.238:27753] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Aug 15 01:09:17.240291 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14328:tid 140275526600448] [remote 39.53.22.238:27753]   File "/home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/wsgi/__init__.py", l$
[Wed Aug 15 01:09:17.240296 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14328:tid 140275526600448] [remote 39.53.22.238:27753]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application  # noqa
[Wed Aug 15 01:09:17.240310 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 14328:tid 140275526600448] [remote 39.53.22.238:27753] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: Check that directory given to ``python-home`` is the same as ``sys.prefix`` for the virtual environment. See docs at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton First sorry for late response. Second `ecom/ecom` is my virtualenv. But I did as mentioned the link I activated my env `source ecom/bin/activate` and ran `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'` it is just giving `/usr`

Comment: After you activate the virtual environment from the command line, run ``which python``. It should not be returning ``/usr`` for a virtual environment.

Comment: `which python` returned `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: There is something wrong with that virtual environment then. What do you get for ``ls -las ecom/bin``. Is there a ``python`` program in that directory? After activating the virtual environment, is full path for ``ecom/bin`` in your ``PATH`` environment variable.

Comment: `0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 7 Jul 16 12:58 python -> python3
   0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 16 Jul 16 12:58 python3 -> /usr/bin/python3`
Is these you are tlking about?

Comment: If you run ``echo $PATH`` after activating the virtual environment, is the directory ``/home/ubuntu/ecom/ecom/bin`` first in that list of paths?

Comment: If you run ``ecom/bin/python`` what does ``sys.prefix`` show then?

Comment: When I run `echo $PATH` it returns `/home/saqib/ecom/ecom/bin` as first path

Comment: And `sys.prefix` returns `/home/googleuser/ecom/ecom
` after running `ecom/bin/python`

Comment: I created this env in my local machine and then copied it on the server as it is. In my knowledge virtualenv can run anywhere

Comment: It is not usually a good idea to copy a virtual environment from one machine to another. If you do, it must be exact same Python version, machine architecture, same versions of system packages etc, and the directory path where created on local machine and that on target machine must be exactly the same. Even then I would not recommend it.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid compiling packages on target machine, create a Python wheelhouse on local machine, copy that to target machine, create virtual environment on target machine and then pip install using the wheelhouse.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid mistake. and thankyou for the answer. I will create a new envirnoment and complie all packages and then run saleor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am answering this question if someone else has a problem. This project was on hold and that is why I am updating it this late. Anyways the issue is that `python-home` should point to your root directory where your `manage.py` is located. And `python-path` should point to your `virtualenv` folder. Thats is.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/ecom

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


    Alias /static /home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/static
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/wsgi>
        <Files __init__.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject2 python-home=/home/ubuntu/ecom/ecom/saleor python-path=/home/ubuntu/ecom/env
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject2
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/ecom/saleor/saleor/wsgi/__init__.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @Graham Dumpleton you have to change your

```
python-home=/home/ubuntu/ecom/ecom
```

Which is not the path to your virtual enviroment.

> Check that directory given to python-home is the same as sys.prefix
>   for the virtual environment.

So you should have something like this:

```
python-home=/home/ubuntu/ecom/venv
```

Comment: You don't have to put the domain name. The value of ``WSGIProcessGroup`` needs to match the name used as value to ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` group. The names can be anything.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton What about `WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-home=/path/to/venv`? The OP has `python-home=/home/ubuntu/ecom/ecom` that doesn't seem a path to virtual enviroment.